# dmesg shows nvme errors but smartctrl shows no errors

Tags: ext4, smartctl, nvme

I keep seeing messages scroll in dmesg

> Jan 27 12:56:11 localhost smartd[1191]: Device: /dev/nvme0, number of Error Log entries increased from 316 to 321

But I ran smartctrl tests on all the partitions of nvme0 and they all passed with no errors. I had my laptop freeze up on me (using Ubuntu) so that is why I am concerned.

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-169-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB
Serial Number:                      S58SNM0W306317Y
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXM7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            254,835,679,232 [254 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5331900fe8
Local Time is:                      Sat Jan 27 13:12:20 2024 CST
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.80W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     6.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.40W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0100W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        38 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    738,705 [378 GB]
Data Units Written:                 806,849 [413 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 65,593,785
Host Write Commands:                24,831,635
Controller Busy Time:               44
Power Cycles:                       77
Power On Hours:                     38
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   1
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      321
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               38 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               34 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

Comment: try with nvme-cli? did you run smartctl on nvme0 or nvme0n1? behavior is sometimes different.

Comment: *I had my laptop freeze up on me* could be a GPU/GPU driver/faulty RAM issue as well.